# Organizing Boards

Tags: trello, trello-boards

It seems that Trello automatically organizes boards based on alphabetical order, but we would like to sort based on priority or be able to drag and drop, similar to cards.

Is there a way to organize boards like that?

Answer (score 4):

In the newest version (as of Jan'14), you can drag'n'drop to reorder starred boards, both in the Boards page, and in the in-board dropdown menu.

See: http://blog.trello.com/we-made-getting-around-trello-lots-faster-with-starred-boards-a-new-boards-page-and-more/

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I started each Board name with a number and this resorted the list in number order

Comment: not ideal, but good hack.

Answer (score 2):

A useful way of positioning certain boards at the top of the list is to pre-pend the board name with a space. This is invisible when displayed in the list.